# Python program getting slowed down severely due to genfromtxt even for a very small 5x5 array

Tags: python, arrays, csv, file-io

I have a python program which takes in two 5 by 8 arrays as input and then calculates about 4000 values from them for getting at the result.
The commented out portion shows my declaration without use of genfromtxt, where the program finishes in 0.2 seconds. If I use genfromtxt as shown, the program takes 4.7 seconds, which is unacceptable for me as this is a demo run for what is going to be a very large program

```
    varcost1=np.genfromtxt('varcost_vr01.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None)
varcost=varcost1
##    varcost=[[110,100,140,120,160,150,200,180],
##             [120,109,153,131,175,164,218,220],
##             [150,136,191,164,218,205,273,250],
##             [180,164,229,196,262,246,327,300],
##             [200,182,255,218,291,273,364,350]]
```

I have used time() to see the execution time. I also tried assigning the array to another variable and then equating it to the original so that there is no risk of the file being read every time the data is needed, but that also doesn't seem to help.

I find this weird because the inputs in question are of a really small size and my system is a relatively modern one:

System Model:   HP ProBook 640 G2, Windows 7, IDLE for Python
System Type:    x64-based PC
Processor:  Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz, 2401 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)

I need to use the genfromtxt functionality because this will be scaled up and then it will be really difficult to test/manipulate. How do I speed up the process?

EDIT: I have found a temporary solution; the genfromtxt was being called in a function which had around 4000 calls. Using genfromtxt only twice, just before the start of the function definition and assigning it to a variable which is then used in the function brings down the time to 0.28 seconds, which is acceptable for me.

Comment: And what's the raw data in `varcost_vr01.csv`? Is it definitely 5 small lines and not some massively weird file with megabytes of space between columns etc..?

Comment: @JonClements Both are 1 kilobyte files - one I typed out in notepad and the other I exported as CSV from MS Excel, identical (and additive) behaviour from both (if only one is read using genfromtxt, then 2.4 seconds for the program)

Comment: When you say you're using `time` to measure things... Are you exclusively doing that for the `np.genfromtxt` - you're not including the time for `numpy` import etc...?

Comment: Ummm... `%timeit np.genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter=',')` gives me 525 µs ± 27.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each) - so you're possibly not timing the right thing or you're loading from magnetic tape? :p

Comment: @JonClements I'm measuring the whole program, starting just after user input ends and stopping just before the program ends. I included the time() just for posting here, even otherwise the process was visibly very slow.

Comment: So you're including the time it takes for `numpy` to import ? And in the timing that shaved off 4 seconds - had you kept *everything* the same except the `np.genfromtxt` line?

Comment: No, I'm starting the timer after the import of numpy

Comment: Can you show the *full* code of both versions that you ran to do your timings?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just shared a major improvement in the latest edit. Ensured that genfromtxt is called only twice. I'll be happy to share the code if it helps.

Comment: Okay - you do realise that `varcost=varcost1` isn't creating a copy it's just creating another reference, right? (mutating one will affect the other - unless you make an explicit copy)

Comment: I'm not sure; as I understand that varcost1 holds the data which it had been assigned to, before any loops happen and varcost accesses the data in varcost1 in each loop, and the genfromtxt call is avoided. Please feel free to correct me, I'm a beginner with some knowledge of programming in some languages..

Comment: Link to the program code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4l-nvGOApEob0hMTVpLQVZEY1k

Comment: At a glance and I don't have time to look more thoroughly - that whole nested `for` loop stuff can be optimised a huge amount and once you've computed it - you'd probably want to store it and load it instead of re-computing... Not sure why you're using a list for `allroutes` when you're using numpy elsewhere... etc... (you're doing a huge amount of unnecessary computational work there)

Comment: Your're right, I'm storing the pattern calculated using the for loop; I do need to optimize it for future runs. I just started using numpy today, was avoiding additional components which make a program less portable..